# How to solve the ipa is invalid issue ? ios

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode6

I am using xcode 6.
I want to validate my project, but I am keeping recieving this error :

The ipa is invalid it does not include a Payload directory

[image]

How could I solve this problem ? I search a the internet a lot , but there is no suggestions that help me?

by the way when I opened new project with same identifier and provision the validate succeed !

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Please mark the correct post as answer!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your `Application requires iPhone environment`, aka `LSRequiresIPhoneOS`, key in your application's `info.plist` file is `true`. If it isn't, Xcode will build an iOS `.ipa` in the OS X applications folder.

Comment: Not worked. for me it is YES. But I tried to localize Info.plist (sme weird experiments), so don't know what to do now and where is the problem..

Comment: My problem solved! Check project - TARGETS - Build settings - Packaging - Info.plist File == "your_project/Info.plist".  Remove substitutes from right side (or first "/" or other doubt symbols and paths) and try.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the key “Application requires iPhone environment” Value is YES

in the info.plist using xcode 6.1 or 6.2

Like this http://xcode5.tistory.com/entry/iOS-The-IPA-is-invalid-it-does-not-include-a-Payload-directory

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for some, worked for me...

I struggled with this for a couple hours, tried several different things that I found through researching all the different solutions people have posted online, but nothing worked. I then went into "edit scheme", then into the "info" section under "run" and found that the "Build configuration" option was set to "debug." I thought this to be odd, so I changed it to "release", and validation finally worked!

I had recently submitted an update a couple weeks earlier, and everything worked fine. I had added localizations to this new update, but didn't see anything that may have caused things in the project to go wrong. I noticed that since my last update though (only two weeks ago) some of my project's data had been automatically reverted back to the first version of the app. For example, my version code was set to 1.0, but the last update was 1.3. Also, my build version went back to 1, but should have been 4. I don't know why this happened, but it did, and I'm guessing that this automatic revert perhaps changed my build configuration also, causing the "IPA invalid" "No payload" error. Any ideas?